# Leaflet markers in joomla are not removed

Tags: php, ajax

I am working on a project and I want to remove the markers from a leaflet map that were added to the map previously.

The problem is that when I want to remove the markers that were added to the map, instead of removing the markers, they are added every time when the function is called over and over again and the old markers are not removed from the map. The function in which the markers are added is a function in which I want to update the markers with the new positions on the map, deleting the old positions of the markers just before adding the new positions. The function uses ajax to position the markers on the map.

Here is the function:

```
function updateVehiclePositions()
{
    var activeInfoWindow;
    var InfoWindow;
    for (var i in vehicles)
    {
        vehicles[i].remove();
    }

    var siteurlvehicles = "<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>"; 

    var pageUrl = "http://site-otl-joomla/index.php/ro/allcategories-ro-ro/uncategorised/3n/templates/protostar/php";

    pageFinalUrl = pageUrl.replace(pageUrl, siteurlvehicles);

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: pageFinalUrl + "templates/protostar/php/get_vehicles_xml.php?line=<?php echo $line; ?>",
        success: function(vehicles) {

            vehicles = JSON.parse(vehicles);

            for (var i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++) {

                var icon = vehicles[i].icon;

                var iconUrl = "http://site-otl-joomla/index.php/ro/allcategories-ro-ro/uncategorised/3n/templates/protostar/php/img/" + icon;

                iconFinalUrl = iconUrl.replace(iconUrl, siteurlvehicles + "templates/protostar/php/img/" + icon);

                var image = new L.icon({
                    iconUrl: iconFinalUrl,
                    iconSize: [16, 16],
                    iconAnchor: [8, 8],
                    popupAnchor: [8, 8]
                });

                var latLng = L.latLng(vehicles[i].lat, vehicles[i].lng);

                var title = vehicles[i].title;
                var vehicleId = vehicles[i].vehicleid;

                vehicles[vehicleId] = createVehicle(latLng, image, i, title);

                if(vehicles[vehicleId]) { 
                    globalMap.removeLayer(vehicles[vehicleId]);

                    console.log(vehicles[vehicleId]);

                }

                vehicles[vehicleId].addTo(globalMap); 
                console.log(vehicles[vehicleId]);  
                delete image;
            }
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function() { updateVehiclePositions(); }, 20000);  
}

function createVehicle(point, image, number, title) {

    var activeInfoWindow;
    var InfoWindow;

    var marker = new L.Marker(point, {icon:image});

    marker.value = number;
    marker.on("click", function() {
        var myHTML = title;
        if (activeInfoWindow) { activeInfoWindow.close(); }
        var infoWindow = L.popup()
            .setLatLng(point)
            .setContent(myHTML)
            .openOn(globalMap);
        activeInfoWindow = InfoWindow;
    });

    return marker;
}
```

Can you help me with the problem that I have? Where is the mistake in my code?

Comment: Welcome to JSE Marcel.  Please take our [tour].  As an aside, when you are merely fetching data from a server request use `GET`; using `POST` should be reserved for times when you are writing/modifying data to your server (there are a few minor exceptions to this rule, of course).  Are you possibly able to craft a small reproducible jsfiddle with some static sample data?  Ultimately, we want to help you sort this out, but if you manage to self-solve this, please post an answer and explain what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long period of time, I have managed to find a solution to my problem. I have decided to rewrite the code from scratch.

The code is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var vehicles = new Array();

var markersLayer;

function initializeGoogleMap()
{

    var googleStreets = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&hl=document.getElementById([<?php echo $lang;?>])',{
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
    });

    var googleSat = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&hl=document.getElementById([<?php echo $lang;?>])',{
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
    });

    var map = L.map('map_canvas', {center: [<?php echo $startLat; ?>, <?php echo $startLng; ?>], layers: [googleStreets,googleSat], zoom: 13.5});
    var baseMaps = {
        "Satellite": googleSat,
        "Map": googleStreets
    };

    L.control.layers(baseMaps).addTo(map);
    googleStreets.addTo(map);

    markersLayer = L.layerGroup();
    map.addLayer(markersLayer);


    globalMap = map;

    function createVehicle(point, image, number, title) {
        var activeInfoWindow;
        var InfoWindow;

        var marker = new L.Marker(point, {icon:image});
        marker.value = number;
        marker.on("click", function() {

        var myHTML = title;
        if (activeInfoWindow) {
            activeInfoWindow.close();
        }
        var infoWindow = L.popup().setLatLng(point).setContent(myHTML).openOn(globalMap);
        activeInfoWindow = InfoWindow;
    });

    return marker;
}

function updateVehiclePositions() {

    var siteurlvehicles = "<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>"; 

    var pageUrl = "http://site-otl-joomla/index.php/ro/allcategories-ro-ro/uncategorised/3n/templates/protostar/php";

    var pageFinalUrl = pageUrl.replace(pageUrl, siteurlvehicles);

    jQuery.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        url: pageFinalUrl + "templates/protostar/php/get_vehicles_xml.php?line=<?php echo $line; ?>",
        success: function(vehicleList) {

            vehicles = JSON.parse(vehicleList);
            for(var i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++) { 
 
                var icon = vehicles[i].icon;
                var iconUrl = "http://site-otl-joomla/index.php/ro/allcategories-ro-ro/uncategorised/3n/templates/protostar/php/img/" + icon;

                var iconFinalUrl = iconUrl.replace(iconUrl, siteurlvehicles + "templates/protostar/php/img/" + icon);

                var image = new L.icon({
                        iconUrl: 
                        iconFinalUrl,
                        iconSize: [16, 16],
                        iconAnchor: [8, 8],
                        popupAnchor: [8, 8]
                    });

                var latLng = new L.latLng(vehicles[i].lat, vehicles[i].lng);

                var title = vehicles[i].title;
                var vehicleId = vehicles[i].vehicleid;

                vehicles[vehicleId] = createVehicle(latLng, image, i, title);

 
                markersLayer.addLayer(vehicles[vehicleId]);
            }
        }
    });
 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        markersLayer.clearLayers(); 
        updateVehiclePositions();
    }, 20000);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's a problem with the scope of the variable `vehicles` which you seem to be using as a global variable and also as the parameter to your function which is called on success of the ajax call.

Try replacing the lines:

```
success: function(vehicles) {

            vehicles = JSON.parse(vehicles);
```

with

```
success: function(vehicleList) {

            vehicles = JSON.parse(vehicleList);
```

UPDATE:

The other problem I think is with your code at

```
for (var i in vehicles)
{
    vehicles[i].remove();
}
```

This is iterating over the properties of the `vehicles` object, and I don't think that that will be the same as iterating through the `vehicles` array. Try replacing this with

```
for (var i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++) {
    vehicles[i].remove();
}
```

Also you can do a `console.log(vehicles)` just above these lines to confirm that this variable holds what you expect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Robbie Jackson! I tried your solution, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @MarcelStiube - ok I found another issue and have added that into the answer

Comment: I have made the requested modifications, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: ok, I'll think you'll have to do some javascript debugging - see eg https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger. Did console.log() give you what you expected? If you get the correct data returned in the ajax call then it's probably not a Joomla issue at all, so posting on this forum may not help.

Comment: I am getting the correct data in the ajax call. I believe that the issue is in these line of code: ```if(vehicles[vehicleId]) { globalMap.removeLayer(vehicles[vehicleId]); }```. The markers doesn't want to be removed by using this function.

Comment: As you haven't posted what the removeLayer function is there's no way anyone can help you. But as the Joomla part seems to be working it would be better to raise any further questions on stackoverflow rather than this forum.

Comment: The removeLayer function is the function that removes all the markers from the map.